# Fail to use pandas to extract the web ALL table content

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use pandas to extract the web ALL table content.

Here are the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link ="http://vip.win007.com/AsianOdds_n.aspx?id=1957300"

macau_asianodds_list = list()

asianodds = pd.read_html(link, flavor='bs4', header = 0)
asianodds[0]
df_NaN = asianodds[0]
asianodds = df_NaN.drop(df_NaN[df_NaN.多盘口 == '多盘口'].index)
asianodds.drop('多盘口', inplace=True, axis=1)
asianodds.drop('历史资料', inplace=True, axis=1)

df1 = asianodds.iloc[0:1]
df2 = asianodds.iloc[1:2]
df3 = asianodds.iloc[2:3]
df4 = asianodds.iloc[3:4]
df5 = asianodds.iloc[4:5]
df6 = asianodds.iloc[5:6]
df7 = asianodds.iloc[6:7]
df8 = asianodds.iloc[7:8]
df9 = asianodds.iloc[8:9]
df10 = asianodds.iloc[9:10]
df11 = asianodds.iloc[10:11]
df12 = asianodds.iloc[11:12]
df13 = asianodds.iloc[12:13]
df14 = asianodds.iloc[13:14]

macau_asianodds = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,
        df11,df12,df13,df14], axis=1, sort=False)

macau_asianodds.to_excel("c:/logs/history/test.xls",index=False)
```

The df1, df2, df3....not in the same row of the excel file. I revised the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to 'flavor=' on read_html().  It can be 'lxml', 'bs4', 'html5lib' and others?

The flavor='bs4' provided all rows.

The flavor='html5lib' provide all rows + a lot of extra info...

Comment: frankr6591, Thanks for your reply. i added flavor='bs4' to the code and it can be shown all the table content. But i got the another problem. The df1, df2, df3....not in the same row of the excel file. I revised the code.